# C++ custom collection reverse_iterator with similar behaviour to std::vector implementation

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have a template based custom collection (as we cannot use std::vector on the interface).  I would like to implement a reverse_iterator specific to this collection. The reverse iterator struct below is a structure nested within the collection class. An iterator (basically a pointer to element type of the collection) is already implemented. This is my first attempt at a reverse iterator.

```
    template <typename T>
    struct reverse_iterator
    {
        typedef T::iterator iterator;
        typedef T& reference;

        inline reverse_iterator(const iterator & it):_it(it){}
        inline reverse_iterator() : _it(0x0)                {}

        inline iterator base() const                        {iterator it = _it; return --it;}

        inline reverse_iterator operator ++ ()              {return reverse_iterator(--_it);}
        inline reverse_iterator operator -- ()              {return reverse_iterator(++_it);}
        inline reverse_iterator operator ++ (int val)       {_it -= val; return reverse_iterator(_it);}
        inline reverse_iterator operator -- (int val)       {_it += val; return reverse_iterator(_it);}
        inline reverse_iterator operator += (int val)       {_it -= val; return reverse_iterator(_it);}
        inline reverse_iterator operator -= (int val)       {_it += val; return reverse_iterator(_it);}

        inline reverse_iterator operator + (int val) const  {iterator it = _it - val; return reverse_iterator(it);}
        inline reverse_iterator operator - (int val) const  {iterator it = _it + val; return reverse_iterator(it);}

        bool operator == (const iterator & other) const     {return other == base();}
        bool operator != (const iterator & other) const     {return other != base();}

        reference operator*() const {return *base();}
        iterator operator->() const {return base();}

    private:    
        iterator _it;
    };
```

1. Is this is workable reverse_iterator or am I missing something ?
2. Can this be improved?

Comment: Did you try [`std::reverse_iterator<iterator>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) yet?

Comment: cannot use std types for reasons beyond my control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for the things mentioned below your implementation is almost the same as the implementation in libstdc++ ([v3](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-3.4/stl__iterator_8h-source.html#l00090), but still somewhat accurate). Note that you're currently missing all non-member functions. All in all you should try to match the [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) interface: if you're ever able to use std types you can happily exchange your `mylab::reverse_iterator` by `std::reverse_iterator`.

### Missing things

1. You're missing all comparison operators between `reverse_iterator`, such as `operator==`,  `operator!=`, `operator<` and so on.

### Strange things

This is basically a list of stuff where your `reverse_iterator` differs from the standard one.

1. Usually the pre-increment/-decrement operators return a reference (`*this`) and not a new object.
2. The post increment/decrement operators shouldn't take a value:

   ```
   inline reverse_iterator operator ++ (int)       {
     reverse_iterator tmp = *this;
     ++*this; // implement post-increment in terms of pre-increment!
     // or --_it;
     return tmp;
   }
   inline reverse_iterator operator -- (int)       { ... }
   ```
3. The compound assignment operators also usually return references.
4. **Your `const iterator&` constructor should be `explicit`**, otherwise one could accidentally mix reverse and normal iterators.
5. Instead of a container type `T` you should use the underlying iterator as template parameter:

   ```
   template <typename Iterator>
   struct reverse_iterator
   {
       typedef Iterator iterator;
       typedef typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference reference;
       ...
   }
   ```

   This enables you to use `reverse_iterator` on anything that `iterator_traits` can handle:

   ```
   template <class Iterator>
   struct iterator_traits{
     typedef typename Iterator::reference reference;
     // Add other things
   };

   template <class T>
   struct iterator_traits<T*>{
     typedef T & reference;
   };
   ```

   With this you can even use `reverse_iterator<int *>` or similar.
6. `operator->` usually returns a pointer to the underlying object, not an intermediary iterator. You might want to add a `pointer` typedef to both your traits and your original iterator.
7. It's ***very*** uncommon to check equality between different types. Remove the `operator==(const iterator&)`.

Comment: Wow! I did not intent to miss the comparison operators. My mistake.
#1,#3. Agree. #2. Right. #4. Good find. #5. I was thinking if there was any necessity to have the reverse_iterator as a template class as the types used by the struct could be typedef-ed before the declaration inside the collection class.
#6. Agreed. #7. Not sure why we need it. Will review the requirements. Thanks for the answer!