# The base() function of reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

From this old question

[C++ custom collection reverse_iterator with similar behaviour to std::vector implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275190/c-custom-collection-reverse-iterator-with-similar-behaviour-to-stdvector-imp)

I thought that the lines (after revising his design a bit)

```
template <typename Iterator>
class reverse_iterator {
    Iterator _it;
public:
    reverse_iterator(const Iterator& it):_it(it) { }
    Iterator base() const {Iterator it = _it; return --it;}
    typename Iterator::value_type& operator*() const {return *base();}
//  ...
};
```

were correct (no one replied that they were incorrect).  But it doesn't give the same output that this test with `std::reverse_iterator` gives:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <iterator>    
#include <vector>  

int main () {
    std::vector<int> myvector = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::next(myvector.begin());
    std::reverse_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator> r(it);
    std::cout << *it << '\n';  // 2
    std::cout << *r << '\n';  // 1
    std::cout << *r.base() << '\n';  // 2
}
```

which seems to show that the lines should instead be

```
template <typename Iterator>
class reverse_iterator {
    Iterator _it;
public:
    reverse_iterator(const Iterator& it):_it(it) { }
    Iterator base() const { return _it; }
    typename Iterator::value_type& operator*() const { return *--base(); }
//  ...
};
```

which would indeed give the same output as with `std::reverse_iterator`.  What is correct here?

Comment: `{Iterator it = _it; return --it;}` can't be right, if only because `_it` may be equal to `begin()` and decrementing it would exhibit undefined behavior. Your alternative implementation looks OK to me. In fact, [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator*) states that `operator*()` should be equivalent to `Iterator tmp = current; return *--tmp;` (where `current` there is the same as your `_it`).

Comment: There are corner cases where `Iterator` is a pointer, and `*--base()` doesn't work on an rvalue. But Igor's `*--tmp` works because `tmp` is an lvalue.